# kubuntu dsl network problems

Tags: 12.04, networking, kubuntu, network-manager, dsl

OK so here is the problem, i want to reinstall kubuntu 12.04 lts on my pc but i cannot connect to any internet, because the network manager wont let me.i have internet through pppoe but the problem is i need to let the "Service" field empty but it wont let me, i encountered this with 12.04.1 but i said "what the heck, lets start install", but to my disapointment i didnt had no network after installation.After that ive downloaded 12.04 dvd again same problem i cannot let "Service" field empty and because of that i have no internet how can i do it?

I had ubuntu 12.04 before with unity and after that i installed kde on it, but because of some unkown issues after sometime my graphic driver broke down, dont know what happened i couldnt install,remove,purge the driver so i installed a fresh copy of kubuntu, all well but i realised that the installment was 12.10 and i wanted 12.04 cause is lts(appearently the downloads arent properly linked).

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve this issue with `pppoeconf` from terminal, but I need to add at `network-manager` from KDE so I can change settings easily when I need to.